# Distributing custom app using Apple Business Manager

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a Flutter Application that needs to be distributed internally and externally using Apple Business Manager. I have reached the point where I can see my application inside the Custom Apps tab on Business Manager. The mode of distribution on App Store Connect has been selected as Private, however, I cannot figure out where to go from here. I have added a user to my organization but I have no way of knowing how that user or users who get added on later will be able to avail the app on their iPhones. I tried going through several Apple documents to find out what to do however, the info on those were not very clear as most of them elaborated on how the entire setup needs to be done prior to Users or organizations being able to access the application. Can someone point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple Business Manager doesn't provide App Distribution functionality.  It only allows organisations to "purchase" custom apps that have been made available to them.

Once an organisation has purchased entitlements there are two distribution methods available:

- The best method is using an MDM/UEM to assign the app to managed devices.  With this method you can remove the app from the device by unassigning it and if the device is removed from management then the app will be deleted.
- The other method is to obtain redemption codes from Apple Business Manager and provide those to users somehow e.g. Email.  Each code can only be used once and once redeemed by a user, you cannot revoke that user's access to the app (The code is redeemed in the App Store and the app is then "owned" by the Apple ID that redeems it).